# Show that $P$ is the union of $k$ chains .

Tags: logic, order-theory

I just started taking an introduction to logic course and came across this problem:

Let $P$ be a partial ordering such that every finite subset of $P$ is the union of $k$ chains. Show that $P$ is the union of $k$ chains.

I tried to do this assuming that $P$ is countable:
Let $P$ be countable and let $A_0$ be a finite subset of $P$. Then we can write $ P\setminus A_0= \cup_{j=1}^{\infty}\{p_j\}$. By assumption, $A_0$ is the union of $k$ chains and for $p_1 \notin A_0$, $A_0 \cup \{p_1\}$ is also a finite subset of $P$ and thus is the union of $k$ chains. By letting $A_n = A_{n-1} \cup \{p_n\}$ we see by induction that $A_n$ is the union of $k$ chains for any $n$ and since $A_n \nearrow P$, we get that $P$ is the union of $k$ chains.

I'm not sure if my last line is correct as I am saying the limit of the $A_n$'s is a $k$-chain.

How else should I go about this? What should I do if $P$ is uncountable?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "$A_0\cup\{p_1\}$ is also a finite subsetof $P$ and thus is the union of $k$ chains" — RIGHT. "i.e. adding $p_1$ just means adding an element to an existing chain" — WRONG.

Comment: **Example.** $P=\{2,3,6,9,\dots\}$ ordered by the relation "$a$ divides $b$" is the union of two chains. The finite subset $A=\{2,3,6\}$ is the union of two chains, say the chains $\{2\}$ and $\{3,6\}$. The set $A\cup\{9\}$ is also the union of two chains, but adding $9$ to one of the "existing chains" won't work. Well, it would work if you'd had the foresight to pick the right two chains for $A$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my post.

Comment: In your paragraph about the countable case, the first four lines simply repeat, extremely verbosely, the **hypothesis**, that for each $n$ the finite set $A_n=\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ is the union of $k$ chains. Then in line 5, out of the blue, with no explanation, "we get that $P$ is the union of $k$ chains."

Comment: This is an easy consequence of the De Bruijn-Erdos Theorem for graphs. Are you familiar with this result?

Comment: Maybe you are expected to use something that was covered in your logic class around the time this problem was assigned? So, what theorems or methods have you learned lately? What is the level of your logic class? What text are you using? I'm not just asking out of curiosity; this question can be answered in a few different ways depending on what you know.

Comment: @halrankard2 The De Bruijn–Erdos theorem, or the Tychonoff product theorem, or the Rado selection principle, or (since the OP says this is from a logic course) the compactness theorem for first-order logic.

Comment: @bof  I just started taking an intro to logic class, so I am about 8 classes in. The only thing we have discussed pertaining to chains is Zorn's lemma. I will look up the above theorems out of curiosity, but these were not covered in class. We have spent a lot of time discussing syntactic and semantic implications as well as the completeness and soundness theorems. Since you suggest to use the compactness theorem, I will try that. I would like to point out that I already stated that I knew line 5 was incorrect below my attempt.

Comment: How for 2 in P, @bof, is  the finite set {2} a union of two chains?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\{2\} = \{2\}\cup \{2\}$. Or, if you prefer disjoint unions, $\{2\} = \{2\}\cup \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a set $I$, and a finite set $A_i$ for each $i\in I$, a choice function $f$ on a subset $X\subseteq I$, selects an element $f(x)\in A_x$ for each $x\in X$.

Suppose for each finite subset $J\subseteq I$ we have a choice function $f_J$ on $J$.

**Rado selection principle**: There is a choice function $f$ on $I$, that on any finite set $J$ agrees with one of the $f_K$, where $K\supseteq J$.

**Solution to your problem:**

Setup:

> Let $I=P$ your poset. Let $A_i=\{1,2,\cdots, k\}$ for each $i\in I$.  For each finite set $J$ let $f_J$ be a choice function, so that the preimage $f_J^{-1}(t)$ is a chain for each $t=1,\cdots,k$.  (The existence of $f_J$ is equivalent to $J$ being a union of $k$ chains).

Applying the Rado selection principle:

> we obtain a choice function $f$ on $I$, which on each finite set agrees with some $f_K$.  Thus if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $f_K(x)=f_K(y)$ for some $K$ and $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$.  Thus $P$ is the union of the $f^{-1}(t)$, for $t=1,\cdots,k$, and each of these is a chain.

---

**Proof of the Rado selection principle from Zorn's lemma:**

Say that a choice function $g$ on a subset $X\subseteq I$ is *extendable* if for all finite subsets $J\subseteq I$, there exists a finite subset $K\supseteq J$, such that $g$ agrees with $f_K$ on $X\cap J$.

We can partially order extendable choice functions:  If $g,h$ are extendable choice functions on subsets $X,Y\subseteq I$ respectively, we say $g\leq h$ whenever $X\subseteq Y$ and $g,h$ agree on $X$.

Note that the empty choice function on the empty set is extendable, as it agrees with any $f_J$ on the empty set.

Suppose we have a chain of extendable choice functions $g_\alpha$ on subsets $X_\alpha\subseteq I$.  Let $X$ be the union of the $X_\alpha$ and let $g$ be the induced choice function on $X$.  We claim that $g$ is extendable:

Given a finite subset $J\subseteq I$, we have $J\cap X=J\cap X_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.  As $g_\alpha$ agrees with some $f_K$ on $X_\alpha\cap J$, we have that $g$ agrees with $f_K$ on $X\cap J$.

Thus applying Zorn's lemma, we may select $f$ to be a maximal extendable choice function. Let $X\subseteq I$ be the domain of $f$. Suppose $X\neq I$ so we have some $y\in I$ with $y\notin X$.

For each $a\in A_y$, let $f_a$ be the extension of $f$ to $X\cup\{y\}$ mapping $y\mapsto a$.

We claim that some $f_a$ is extendable.  If not, we must have finite subsets $J_a\subseteq I$ for each $a \in A_y$ such that $f_a$ does not  agree with any $f_K$ on $(X\cup\{y\})\cap J_a$.  Note for all $a\in A_y$ we must have $y\in J_a$.

Let $J$ be the union of the $J_a$ and let $f$ agree with $f_K$ on $J$, for some $K\supseteq J$.  Let $a=f_K(y)$.  Then $K\supseteq J\supseteq J_a$ and $f_a$ agrees with $f_K$ on $(X\cup\{y\})\cap J_a$, giving the desired contradiction.

Thus $f<f_a$ for some $a\in A_y$, contradicting the maximality of $f$.  We conclude that $X=I$.  Thus $f$ is a choice function on $I$, and as it is extendable, it satisfies the required property.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy proof using the compactness theorem for first-order logic. It applies to posets of arbitrary cardinality.

Let $L = \{\leq, C_1,\dots,C_k\}\cup \{c_a\mid a\in P\}$, where $\leq$ is a binary relation, the $C_i$ are unary relations, and the $c_a$ are constant symbols (one for each element of the poset).

Consider the theory $T$ containing:

- The poset axioms for $\leq$.
- Axioms asserting that each $C_i$ defines a chain.
- An axiom asserting that every element is in one of the $C_i$.
- The diagram of $P$.

Now $T$ is finitely satisfiable: Any finite subset $T'\subseteq T$ mentions only finitely many constant symbols from a finite subset $P'\subseteq P$. We can turn $P'$ into a model of $T'$ by interpreting $\leq$ and the constant symbols in the obvious ways and interpreting the $C_i$ as chains whose union is $P'$.

By compactness, $T$ has a model $\mathbb{P}$. Now $\mathbb{P}$ is a poset which is a union of $k$ chains (the $C_1^\mathbb{P},\dots,C_k^{\mathbb{P}}$), and it contains an isomorphic copy of $P$ as a substructure (the interpretations of the constants). Then $P$ is a union of restrictions of the $k$ chains: $C_i^\mathbb{P}\cap P$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(P,\preceq)$ be a poset. Then $P$ is the union of $k$ chains if and only if each finite subset of $P$ is the union of $k$ chains.

We define a propositional language $L$ to be the set having propositional atoms $p_{ai}$, for each element $a\in P$ and each $1\leq i\leq k$. An atom $p_{ai}$ expresses *element $a$ is in the $i^{th}$ chain* when true. Then we define $C_{k}(P)$ to be the set of $L$-formulas:

1. $(p_{a1}\vee\ldots\vee p_{ak})$ for all $a\in P$.
2. $\neg(p_{ai}\wedge p_{bi})$ for all incomparable $a,b\in P$ and $1 \leq i\leq k$.

Note that, when true, 1. expresses *each element $a\in P$ is in at least one chain*, and 2. expresses *any two incomparable elements $a,b\in P$ cannot be in the same chain*.

Now we will prove the $\Leftarrow$ implication by showing that $C_{k}(P)$ is satisfiable and use any $L$-assignment satisfying $C_{k}(P)$ to express $P$ as the union of $k$ chains.

First, we prove that $C_{k}(P)$ is finitely satisfiable. Indeed, suppose that $S$ is a finite subset of $C_{k}(P)$. Then the elements of $P$ mentioned in $S$ constitute a finite subset $P_{S}\subseteq P$, and restricting $\preceq$ to this subset yields a finite poset $(P_{S},\preceq)$. By hypothesis $P_{S}$ is the union of $k$ chains, say $X_{1},\ldots, X_{k}$. Then we define an $L$-assignment $\nu$ by
$$\nu(p_{ai})=\rm{T}\rm{\;\;iff\;\;} a\in X_{i}.$$
Clearly $\nu$ satisfies $S$ and, by the Compactness Theorem, $C_{k}(P)$ is satisfiable.

Second, note that if $\nu$ is an $L$-assignment satisfying $C_{k}(P)$ we can define for each $1\leq i\leq k$ the set
$$X_{i} = \{a\in P : \nu(p_{ai}) = \mbox{T}\},$$
which, by 2. will be a chain. When this is combined with 1. we have that $P=X_{1}\cup\ldots\cup X_{k}$, as desired.

The $\Rightarrow$ implication is quite straightforward because if $P$ is the union of $k$ chains $X_{1},\ldots, X_{k}$ and $P_{0}$ is a any subset of $P$, then the sets $Y_{i}=P_{0}\cap X_{i}$, $1\leq i\leq k$ are $k$ chains whose union is $P_{0}$.