# Partial ordering and union of chains

Tags: logic, order-theory

I’ve just started a logic course and I came across this problem.

Let $P,\leq_p$ be a partial ordering, and let $k$ be a positive integer.

1. Use the Compactness Theorem to show that $P$ is the union of $k$ chains if and only if each finite subset of $P$ is the union of $k$ chains.

How can I prove that if $P$ is the union of $k$ chains then each finite subset of $P$ is the union of $k$ chains.

Comment: "Finite" has nothing to do with it. If $P$ is the union of $k$ chains, then any subset of $P$ is the union of $k$ chains. **Hint.** If $Q\subseteq P$ and if $C$ is a chain in $P$ then $C\cap Q$ is a chain in $Q$.

Comment: Does this hold even when $C$$\cap$$Q$ is empty?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Does a chain have to be nonempty? Is the empty set a "finite subset of $P$"?

Comment: @DavidOkogbenin: The empty set is a subset of $P$. Does it have any incomparable elements? No, because it has no elements at all. Therefore it is vacuously true that its elements are all comparable and hence that it’s a chain in $P$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. I see what you mean. I’m curious, let $Q$$\subseteq$$P$ and two sets $A$ and $B$ are both chains of $P$. If both $A$$\cap$$Q$ and $B$$\cap$$Q$ are empty sets then they are not two distinct subsets of Q. Can we still say that Q is a union of $k$ chains?

Comment: @DavidOkogbenin: In this context *union of $k$ chains* must be understood to mean *union of at most $k$ chains*, as otherwise the theorem is clearly false.

Comment: @Brain M. Scott: Is that the case in this specific context I suggested? Or is it the case whenever we talk about partial ordering and “union of k sets”?

Comment: @DavidOkogbenin: It’s the case here, but in general you’ll have to determine from the context whether the looser reading is intended.

Comment: The same question is essentially asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844145/show-that-p-is-the-union-of-k-chains/4432240#4432240